# Updated Drivers - Command Prompt periodic executes

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-10, drivers

Well just recently I updated my drivers a bit ago and I would rather not have to rollback my drivers, but is there anyway I can track what program or the source of this commmand prompt that keeps opening? Is there a event that logs when a command prompt is opened or a bat file is executed?

Thanks,

Matthew

Comment: Autoruns will help you identify the entry starting this command.

Comment: @Ramhound What is Autoruns? Is it a program pre-installed on windows or a program I have to download?

Comment: [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)

Comment: @Ramhound I couldn't find one entry to match up when the command prompt opens up. Is there another suggestion you have in mind?

Comment: You need to disable everything except what is needed to boot to determine what is starting it.